# change background-color when there is no content in php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a php/wordpress website in which I want to hide the background-color when there is no content.

The php code which I am using is:

```
<div class="featured-block__content">
    <h1 class="featured-block__tag"><?php echo esc_html( explode('|',get_the_title())[1]); ?></h1>
</div>
```

The css code for the above html/php code is:

```
.featured-block__content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 85px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 0.831;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 85px;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that where there is no content inside h1 tag, the background-color should be `background-color:
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

At this moment where there is content inside h1 tag, the background-color is `background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
<?php
    $h1_content = esc_html(explode('|', get_the_title())[1]);
?>

<div class="featured-block__content <?= trim($h1_content) === '' ? 'no-h1' : ''; ?>">
    <h1 class="featured-block__tag"><?= $h1_content; ?></h1>
</div>
```

With the following additional CSS:

```
.featured-block__content.no-h1 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: The css is set for `div` not for `h1` tag.

Comment: the css set for `.featured-block__content` is having a conflict with `.featured-block__content.no-h1`

Answer (score 1):

In order to have PHP control the CSS, you'll need to output a new rule to DOM that the CSS can target.

In this case, you can add a class to the `<h1>`, by simply `echo`ing out the desired class name when there's no content. [`esc_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) returns an empty string, so you can do a check against `""`.

The following adds a class `black` when this content is absent:

```
<h1 class="featured-block__tag" <?php if (esc_html(explode('|',get_the_title())[1]) === "") { echo "black"; } ?>>
  <?php echo esc_html(explode('|',get_the_title())[1]); ?>
</h1>
```

From here you can craft CSS that applies the desired rule to the new selector:

```
.black {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<h1 class="<?php esc_html( explode('|',get_the_title())[1]) === '' ? 'featured-block__tag bg-class1' : 'featured-block__tag'?>"><?php echo esc_html( explode('|',get_the_title())[1]); ?></h1>
```

and css

```
.bg-class1{
background-color: #yourcolor
}
```